# Choose your own story game loop requires user input - having issue with the prompt repeating itself when one of the options is given

Tags: java, loops, input

I am making a Choose Your Own Story game just as a little project to help me learn Java, and I don't know why this loop is behaving the way it is.

The issue is if you enter B when it prompts you to choose an option, it repeats the prompt, "Choose a response:". And if you enter B again, it outputs the right thing. If you enter A, it works fine the first time. I don't know why it takes two times for B to work.

I know the code is probably pretty bad other than that as well, so any other advice is also welcome.

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String storyBlock = "one";
        String option;
        ArrayList<Choices> choiceRepo = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Story> storyRepo = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean continueFlag = true;

        Story one = new Story("one", "The many rolling fields within Argonia are ideal for\n" +
                "raising sheep, which is what my family has done for generations. In my grandfather's\n" +
                "day, our village was known all round for having some of the best sheep in the land.\n" +
                "It's not anymore. For years we've barely had enough sheep to help keep our family fe\n " +
                "and clothed. It's been tough ever since the Ostians invaded our land and pillaged our towns\n" +
                "and villages. After years of teetering on the edge of warfare, our countries finally clashed.\n" +
                "We lost, obviously. Ostia is a much rougher country than ours, and it didn't take long for our\n" +
                "peace seeking king to surrender his country. Though naive, I have to respect him for doing\n" +
                "what he thought would save the most lives. And maybe it did save the most lives, but at the\n" +
                "steep price of our freedom and well being. My village has struggled, but it hasn't been as\n" +
                "bad as some of the villages that aren't as far out in the hills as we are. I've heard rumors that\n" +
                "the Dark Hordes have taken to ravaging the countryside again, though, so it's only a matter\n" +
                "of time until something very bad happens.\n" +
                "The thought of them coming to my village and having to defend it makes me...\n");
        storyRepo.add(one);

        Choices ch1ChoiceA = new Choices("one", "A",
                "frightened", "twoA");
        choiceRepo.add(ch1ChoiceA);

        Choices ch1ChoiceB = new Choices("one", "B",
                "faintly excited at the notion of getting to fight", "twoB");
        choiceRepo.add(ch1ChoiceB);

        Story twoA = new Story("twoA", "...frightened. The Dark Horde is notorious for their savagery,\n" +
                " and the king lets them loose to keep the populous of our country in fear of him. Their warriors\n" +
                "are cold blooded killers, and their mages are even worse. Just thinking of coming into contact\n" +
                "with them makes me stir from the place I have been sitting on the hill. I look up and after a\n" +
                "quick count I realize that Pud has gone missing. That fluffer, always going over one hill or\n" +
                "another. I just hope he hasn't gotten lost in the woods again. I might have to chase off another\n" +
                "bear.");
        storyRepo.add(twoA);

        Story twoB = new Story("twoB", "...faintly excited at the notion of getting to fight. Though\n" +
                " the Dark Horde is notorious for their savagery, I would almost welcome a chance to fight some\n" +
                "of them. The king lets them loose to keep the populous of our country in fear of him.  Their\n" +
                "warriors are cold blooded killers, and their mages are even worse. This makes me concerned for\n" +
                "my family and friends, but inside myself I can feel a craving for the adventure they would\n" +
                "bring. While tending the flock I have fought bears, cougars, and even run into some roving hob\n" +
                "goblins. My job has been to keep the flock safe, and I am very capable. And it also would give\n" +
                "me a chance to practice the sword skills my father has been teaching me since he came back from\n" +
                "the war that we lost. After a quick count realize that Pud has gone missing. That fluffer,\n" +
                "always going over one hill or another. I just hope he hasn't gotten lost in the woods again.");
        storyRepo.add(twoB);

        Choices ch2Choice = new Choices("twoA", "A", "Continue", "three");
        choiceRepo.add(ch2Choice);

        while (continueFlag) {
            ArrayList<Choices> specificChoices = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Story story : storyRepo) {
                if (story.storyName.equals(storyBlock)) {
                    story.printStory();
                    for (Choices choice : choiceRepo) {
                        if (choice.storyBlock.equals(storyBlock)) {
                            choice.printChoices();
                            specificChoices.add(choice);
                        }
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("Choose a response: ");
                option = reader.nextLine();

                if (!option.equals("A") &&
                    !option.equals("B") &&
                    !option.equals("Exit")) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input. Enter A, B or Exit");
                    option = reader.nextLine();
                }

                if (option.equals("Exit")) {
                    continueFlag = false;
                    break;
                }



                for (Choices specificChoice : specificChoices) {
                    if (specificChoice.option.equals(option)) {
                        storyBlock = specificChoice.result;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, instead of using a lot of `if`s, you could use `switch`. It would lower the amount of code you have, and potentially solve your problem.

Comment: I'll try that when I get home later, thanks!
It's such an odd thing it's doing... I have no idea why it's doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing the nested for statement that went through the choicesRepo and put it by itself. In my code above, it was nested within the for statement that cycled through the storyRepo, but I took it out of there and it is working as it should now. Not really sure why it was causing it to do that, but oh well, it works now.